# localStorage not working on Mozilla Firefox 22.0 for Ubuntu Canconical 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, mozilla

I have a web page with tw forms on it. A button is located underneath them. When I click on the button I toggle the forms show/hide with fadeIn/fadeOut. I have added the functionality so that even when I refresh the page the form which was first the current one remains the current one. I used html5 `localStorage` for that. I works perfectly in Chrome but it doesnot work in Mozilla Firefox 22.0 for Ubuntu Canconical 1.0.

[jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tHLVE/)

**HTML:**

```
<section id="content">
    <div id="logo" style="margin-left: 0;"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <form id="sign_up" action="login.php" method="post">
            <table style="margin: 0px auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"> <span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 2em; color: Gray;">Sign Up</span>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="required" maxlength="15" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="required" />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password" required="required" />
                        <br />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="right">
                    <td>
                        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign Up" name="submit_sign_up">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <form id="sign_in" action="login.php" method="post">
            <table style="margin: 0 auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"> <span style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 2em; color: Gray;">Sign In</span>

                    </td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required="required" maxlength="15" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_]{1,15}$" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required="required" />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="right">
                        <td>
                            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Sign In" name="submit_sign_in">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <input id="sign_up_btn" class="btn" type="submit" style=" font-weight:bold; height:40px; width: 292px;" value="Create An Account"></input>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {
    margin-top: 10%;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #aaa inset;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sign_in, #sign_up {
    border: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    width: 292px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 1px #000;
}
#sign_up {
    display: none;
    max-height: 275px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $sUp = $("#sign_up"),
        $sIn = $("#sign_in");

    $("#content").on('click', "#sign_up_btn", function () {

        $sIn.stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $sUp.fadeIn(800);
        });
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $(this).attr({
                value: "Already have an account?",
                id: "sign_in_btn"
            }).fadeIn(800);
        });
        localStorage.setItem('lastForm', 'sign_up');
    }).on('click', "#sign_in_btn", function () {

        $sUp.stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $sIn.fadeIn(800);
        });
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(800, function () {
            $(this).attr({
                value: "Create An Account",
                id: "sign_up_btn"
            }).fadeIn(800);
        });
        localStorage.setItem('lastForm', 'sign_in');
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('lastForm') == "sign_up") {
        $sIn.fadeOut(0);
        $sUp.fadeIn(0);
    }
});
```

**How can I make this `cross-browser` compatible?**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

localstorage.lastform="sign_in";

Comment: I tried it but it's not working! I tried localStorage.setItem aswell but no luck :(